# Find duplicated nested lists in a list

Tags: python, list, nested, duplicates, sublist

```
[[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 10.0], [1.0, 11.0], [1.0, 12.0], [1.0, 13.0]],
 [[2.0, 1.0], [2.0, 10.0], [2.0, 11.0], [2.0, 12.0], [2.0, 13.0]],
 [[3.0, 1.0], [3.0, 10.0], [3.0, 11.0], [3.0, 12.0], [3.0, 13.0]],
 [[4.0, 1.0], [4.0, 10.0], [4.0, 11.0], [4.0, 12.0], [4.0, 13.0]],
 [[4.0, 1.0], [4.0, 10.0], [4.0, 11.0], [4.0, 12.0], [4.0, 13.0]]]
```

If I have a list like this, how do I return the duplicate rows as different groups?

I don't know how to compare if two lists are same when there are sub-list in them.

For this problem, the ideal output would be:

[[[4.0, 1.0], [4.0, 10.0], [4.0, 11.0], [4.0, 12.0], [4.0, 13.0]],

[[4.0, 1.0], [4.0, 10.0], [4.0, 11.0], [4.0, 12.0], [4.0, 13.0]]]

Comment: Could you please show the desired output of this example?

Comment: Any is fine. The point is find duplicate rows

Comment: ok let me put it that way, it is not clear to me what you mean by "return duplicate rows as different groups". A desired output would clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: sorry about that, just updated

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort your data and make each row a tuple to be able to group them. Then check if there are groups with more than 1 element -> duplicates.

Input:

```
ll = [[[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 10.0], [1.0, 11.0], [1.0, 12.0], [1.0, 13.0]],
 [[2.0, 1.0], [2.0, 10.0], [2.0, 11.0], [2.0, 12.0], [2.0, 13.0]],
 [[3.0, 1.0], [3.0, 10.0], [3.0, 11.0], [3.0, 12.0], [3.0, 13.0]],
 [[4.0, 1.0], [4.0, 10.0], [4.0, 11.0], [4.0, 12.0], [4.0, 13.0]],
 [[4.0, 1.0], [4.0, 10.0], [4.0, 11.0], [4.0, 12.0], [4.0, 13.0]]]
```

```
import itertools
l = [tuple(sorted(lst)) for lst in ll]

out = []
for k, g in itertools.groupby(l):
    g = list(g)
    if len(g)>1:
        out.append(g)

print(out)
```

```
[[([4.0, 1.0], [4.0, 10.0], [4.0, 11.0], [4.0, 12.0], [4.0, 13.0]),
  ([4.0, 1.0], [4.0, 10.0], [4.0, 11.0], [4.0, 12.0], [4.0, 13.0])]]
```

or as one-liner:

```
out = list(filter(lambda s: len(s) > 1, [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby([tuple(sorted(lst)) for lst in ll])]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all those nested elements whose count is greater than one and then keep them in List comprehension.

```
l=[[[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 10.0], [1.0, 11.0], [1.0, 12.0], [1.0, 13.0]],
 [[2.0, 1.0], [2.0, 10.0], [2.0, 11.0], [2.0, 12.0], [2.0, 13.0]],
 [[3.0, 1.0], [3.0, 10.0], [3.0, 11.0], [3.0, 12.0], [3.0, 13.0]],
 [[4.0, 1.0], [4.0, 10.0], [4.0, 11.0], [4.0, 12.0], [4.0, 13.0]],
 [[4.0, 1.0], [4.0, 10.0], [4.0, 11.0], [4.0, 12.0], [4.0, 13.0]]]

[x for x in l if l.count(x)>1]

#output
[[[4.0, 1.0], [4.0, 10.0], [4.0, 11.0], [4.0, 12.0], [4.0, 13.0]],
[[4.0, 1.0], [4.0, 10.0], [4.0, 11.0], [4.0, 12.0], [4.0, 13.0]]]
```